# Unable to exit Sql cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

This is hard for me to explain but I have tried my best to make it as easy for you all as I can.

I have two tables. One stores information about customer `tbl_installations`. Another his internet bills `tbl_bills` (this one is more important).

**tbl_installations**

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_installations](
        [SrNo] [int] IDENTITY(1000,1) NOT NULL,
        [name] [varchar](200) NULL,
        [email] [varchar](100) NULL,
        [phone] [varchar](20) NULL,
        [plandesc] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [plancost] [money] NULL,
        [amtpaid] [money] NULL,
        [amtbalance] [money] NULL,
        [address] [varchar](500) NULL,
        [referencename] [varchar](20) NULL,
        [installationdate] [date] NULL,
        [planduration] [int] NULL,
        [MkrId] [varchar](20) NULL,
        [MkrDt] [datetime] NULL,
        [FromDate] [datetime] NULL,
        [ToDate] [datetime] NULL,
        [ExpiryDate] [datetime] NULL,
        [Status] [varchar](20) NULL,
        [CustomerId] [varchar](20) NULL,
        [ServiceTax] [money] NULL,
        [TotalAmt] [money] NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**tbl_bills**

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Bills](
        [Srno] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [CustomerId] [varchar](20) NULL,
        [PlanDuration] [int] NULL,
        [Amount] [money] NULL,
        [PaidAmt] [money] NULL,
        [discount] [money] NULL,
        [PlanDesc] [varchar](20) NULL,
        [FromDate] [datetime] NULL,
        [ToDate] [datetime] NULL,
        [MkrId] [varchar](20) NULL,
        [MkrDt] [datetime] NULL,
        [ServiceTax] [money] NULL,
        [TotalAmt] [money] NULL,
        [PendingAmt]  AS ([TotalAmt]-([PaidAmt]+[discount])),
        [PaidStatus] [varchar](10) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**THIS SCRIPT WILL GIVE YOU DATA THAT I HAVE:**

```
     insert into tbl_installations(name,email,phone,plandesc,plancost,amtpaid,amtbalance,address,referencename,installationdate,planduration,MkrId,
     MkrDt,FromDate,ToDate,ExpiryDate,Status,CustomerId,ServiceTax,TotalAmt)
     values('Gulzar','asdasd','3242342',null,null,null,null,'asda asd aada','ref name',GETDATE()-4,1,'arbaaz', GETDATE(),null,null,
     null,'INSTALLED','C2002',null,null )

     insert into tbl_bills (PlanDuration,Amount,PaidAmt,discount,PlanDesc,FromDate,ToDate,PaidStatus,MkrId,MkrDt,ServiceTax,TotalAmt,CustomerId)                      
     values(1,800,600,0,'1MB',GETDATE()-4,DATEADD(month,1, GETDATE()-4),'PAID','Arbaaz',getdate(),800*(12.36/100),800+800*(12.36/100),'C2001')
```

`PendingAmt` in tbl_bills is a computer column which calculates the pending amount based on `totalamt - (paidamt+discount)`

`tbl_bills.Amount`  is the subsription cost eg: 800
`tbl_bills.TotalAmt`  is sum of Amount+ServiceTax

**Scenario**

**First Month:**

Customer's subsription cost(Amount) is 800
PaidAmt=600
ServiceTax=98.88
TotalAmt=898.88
PendingAmt=298.88(computed field)

**Second Month:**

Customer still has same subscription worth 800 (total 898.88)
But he pays 1100 so that he settles some of pending amount. 
This 1100 must first settle all the previous pending amounts first(by updating `tbl_bills.paidamt` and then what ever is left should be inserted as a brand new row in the same table.

**HERE IS MY FAILED ATTEMPT :**

THIS KEEPS ON RUNNING ENDLESSLY

```
declare @srno as int=0              
declare @Cid as  varchar(20)='C2001'
declare @PlanDuration as int=1         
declare @Amount as money=800             
declare @PlanDesc as varchar(20)='1MB'
declare @FromDate as datetime ='2014-11-11'              
declare @ToDate as datetime='2014-12-11'              
declare @PaidStatus as varchar(20)              
declare @MkrId as varchar(20)='arbaaz'       
declare @status as varchar(20)='PAID'  
declare @Discount as money=0
declare @PaidAmt as money=1100              
--as              
if(@status='INSTALLED')        
BEGIN         
 insert into tbl_bills (PlanDuration,Amount,PaidAmt,discount,PlanDesc,FromDate,ToDate,PaidStatus,MkrId,MkrDt,ServiceTax,TotalAmt,CustomerId)                      
 values(@PlanDuration,@Amount,@paidamt,@discount,@plandesc,@FromDate,@ToDate,'PAID','Arbaaz',getdate(),@Amount*(12.36/100),@Amount+@Amount*(12.36/100),@Cid)                      


 if((select sum(PendingAmt) from tbl_Bills where CustomerId=@cid)=0 )  
 begin  
 update tbl_installations set Status='PAID' ,ExpiryDate=@ToDate where CustomerId=@Cid        
 end  
 else  
 begin  
 update tbl_installations set Status='UNPAID' ,ExpiryDate=@ToDate where CustomerId=@Cid        
 end  
END        
ELSE        
 BEGIN        

   declare @pAmt as money   
 select  @pAmt=sum(PendingAmt) from tbl_Bills where CustomerId=@Cid  

 declare @Amt as money =@Amount  
 select @Amt=@Amt  

 --select  srno from tbl_Bills where CustomerId=@Cid and PendingAmt<>0 order by ToDate  

 if(@pAmt>0)  
 BEGIN------------------------  
 DECLARE @ColExpir datetime  
DECLARE @ColFallprotec datetime  
DECLARE @CurSrno int  
--------------------------------------------------------  
DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR  
SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD  
FOR  
 select  srno from tbl_Bills where CustomerId=@Cid and PendingAmt<>0 order by todate  
OPEN @MyCursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor  
INTO @CurSrno  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
IF(@Amt>0)  
BEGIN  
declare @PendingAtCurSrno money   
select @PendingAtCurSrno=pendingamt from tbl_Bills where SrNo=@CurSrno  
print @CurSrno  -----
print @PendingAtCurSrno ----
if(@Amt>@PendingAtCurSrno)  
begin  

update tbl_Bills set PaidAmt=TotalAmt where SrNo=@CurSrno  
select @Amt=@Amt-@PendingAtCurSrno  
print '1st'----
print @amt----
    if(@amt=0)
    begin
    CLOSE @MyCursor  --tried break and return here too
DEALLOCATE @MyCursor  --
    end
end  
else  
begin  
update tbl_Bills set PaidAmt=paidamt+@Amt where SrNo=@CurSrno  
select @Amt=0  
print '2nd'
print @amt----
    if(@amt=0)
    begin
        CLOSE @MyCursor  --tried break and return here too
DEALLOCATE @MyCursor  
    end
end  
END  
END  


FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor  
INTO @PendingAtCurSrno  
END  
CLOSE @MyCursor  
DEALLOCATE @MyCursor  
END-------------------------  
if(@Amt>0)  
begin  
 insert into tbl_bills (PlanDuration,Amount,PaidAmt,discount,PlanDesc,FromDate,ToDate,PaidStatus,MkrId,MkrDt,ServiceTax,TotalAmt,CustomerId)                      
 values(@PlanDuration,@Amount,@Amt,@discount,@plandesc,@FromDate,@ToDate,'PAID','Arbaaz',getdate(),@Amount*(12.36/100),@Amount+@Amount*(12.36/100),@Cid)                      
end  

  if((select sum(PendingAmt) from tbl_Bills where CustomerId=@cid)=0 )  
 begin  
 update tbl_installations set Status='PAID' ,ExpiryDate=@ToDate where CustomerId=@Cid        
 end  
 else  
 begin  
 update tbl_installations set Status='UNPAID' ,ExpiryDate=@ToDate where CustomerId=@Cid        
 end
```

Not only does it keep running endlessly , it keeps updating the `paidamt` over and over again and never gets to the point where it should insert another row with remaining amount.

Comment: What result does "select  srno from tbl_Bills" gives. I mean count?

Comment: @PareshJadhav it gives the srno (identity field) of the bills where pendingamt>0

Comment: That's a lot of code to throw at us and expect us to debug for you. Try trimming the code down to the smallest example that exhibits the problem and posting that instead. The usual problem with cursors not ending is forgetting to `fetch` from the cursor both above the loop and at the end, inside the loop. I can't actually see if that's the problem here.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever most of the code that I have posted is Create and insert. I thought it would be easier for you guys to understand the question if I gave create and insert script itself instead of table structure. 

The problem is that the first par of the cursor `if(@Amt>@PendingAtCurSrno) ` keeps iterating endlessly.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  if you can run the scripts on your computer I am sure you will be able to find out where the noob(me) is going wrong.

Comment: If you indent your code in the management studio, you will find `FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor ` will be outside your `WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN` Block.